# passing arrays between functions c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, arguments

I have looked around, and can't find anywhere that explicitly answers how to pass an array from function1, class1 to function2, class2.

This is my code.

**Game Class**

```
void Game::userInputNumbers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    std::cin >> myNumbers[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        std::cout << myNumbers[i] << "   ";
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
game.userInputNumbers(); 
user.setTicket(int a, myNumbers[6], username);
```

**User Class**

```
void User::setTicket(int i, int myNumbers[6], std::string username)
{
    std::ofstream fout (username + "Ticket" + a + ".txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    fout << myNumbers[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I will probably have to declare the array as static (not really sure how, or what the implications of that are) and that I will have to use pointers in some form.

Also please note, username and int a have been declared elsewhere in the program and work for other functions so I'm not worried about those, and I have left out all unnecessary code such as my includes as again the rest of the program compiles fine

Thanks in advance

Comment: Function call in the main method should be this way `user.setTicket(a, myNumbers, username);` . Isn't it?

Comment: Either use pointer + count of elements OR (much better) use a `std::vector`.

Comment: yes I think you are right

Comment: can i manipulate a vector in a similar way to an array, or is it styled more like a linked list?

Comment: A `vector` is a dynamic array and guarantees O(1) indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using std::vector instead of a normal array.

There are a couple of ways you can do this, one is something like this:

```
gameObject.userInputNumbers();
userObject.setTicket(value, gameObject.getMyNumbers(), username);
```

Comment: this worked thanks, will research into vectors thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a here:

```
user.setTicket(int a, myNumbers[6], username);
```

Instead, use:

```
user.setTicket(a, myNumbers[6], username);
```

Also, when passing an array, you don't need to include the array length:

```
user.setTicket(a, myNumbers, username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples found here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

for your case this is how you would do it:

```
// arrays as parameters
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void SetArray (int& arg[]) {
  for (int i=0; i<arg.size(); ++i)
    cin >> arg[i];
}

int main ()
{
  int myNumbers[6];
  SetArray(myNumbers);
}
```